Using an argument from a resolver in the resolver of a children field on graphene, python 3.11
I'm trying to use an argument from a resolver of a class in the resolver of a field in the same class in Flask. Is it possible?
My classes look something like this:
from graphene import Int, ObjectType, String, Boolean, Field, List, Mutation, InputObjectType, ID
from services import Service

class ChildrenElement(ObjectType):
    id=ID()
    some_data=String()

class FatherElement(ObjectType):
    id = ID()
    children_element = Field(lambda: ChildrenElement)
    other_element = String()

    def resolve_children_element(root, info):
        return Service.find_by_father(root.get('id'))

    @classmethod
    def resolver_find_element(cls, id, aditional_argument):
        return Service.find_by_id(id, aditional_argument)


I found a way, but I have to add another element to the class and it may be confusing in the documentation
from graphene import Int, ObjectType, String, Boolean, Field, List, Mutation, InputObjectType, ID
from services import Service

class ChildrenElement(ObjectType):
    id=ID()
    some_data=String()

class FatherElement(ObjectType):
    id = ID()
    children_element = Field(lambda: ChildrenElement)
    other_element = String()
    aditional_argument = String()

    def resolve_children_element(root, info):
        return Service.find_by_father(root.get('id'), root.get('aditional_argument'))

    @classmethod
    def resolver_find_element(cls, id, aditional_argument):
        returner_element = Service.find_by_id(id, aditional_argument)
        returner_element['aditional_argument'] = aditional_argument
        return returner_element

class QueryElement(ObjectType):
    find_element = Field(FatherElement, id=Int(required=True), aditional_argument=String(required=False))

    def resolve_find_element(self, info, id, aditional_argument):
        return FatherElement.resolver_find_element(id, aditional_argument)

